# Mike Oldfield - Tubular Bells - John Peel version

Tags: recording, mike-oldfield

Originally, [Vivian Stanshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivian_Stanshall) of the [Bonzo Dog Doo-Dah Band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonzo_Dog_Doo-Dah_Band) performed the 'narration' on part one of [*Tubular Bells*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_Bells).

I recall a remix version, created I think for the BBC on one of the *Tubular Bells* anniversaries which was a complete re-recording using mainly sythesisers. This version was 'narrated' by the DJ [John Peel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Peel) and included the line:

> A computer approximation of Tubular Bells

Is this version available to buy anywhere?

Comment: [Related Meta discussion](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/70/47).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's on Soundcloud, though I can't find it anywhere to buy.

https://soundcloud.com/johnpeelarchive/mike-oldfield-john-peel

Comment: Cool - I'll have a listen when I'm connected to a network that doesn't block streaming music sites :)

Comment: I tapped into it at about 5:45 just in time to hear your quote. Nice.